# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, post, route

Obtive esse Erro ao colocar um projeto no servidor e tentar inserir um produto no banco de dados.

Erro

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong. (1/1)
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 251)

Web.php

```
route::GET('/','ProdutoController@lista');

Route::GET('/welcome', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::group(['prefix' => 'produtos'], function(){
    Route::GET('/', 'ProdutoController@lista');
    Route::GET('/json', 'ProdutoController@listaJson');
    Route::GET('/mostra/{id}', 'ProdutoController@mostra');
    Route::GET('/novo', 'ProdutoController@novo');
    Route::POST('/adiciona', 'ProdutoController@adiciona');
    Route::GET('/remove/{id}', 'ProdutoController@remove');
});

Route::GET('/leitura', 'ProdutoController@LerTXT');
Route::GET('/login', 'LoginController@form');
Route::POST('/login', 'LoginController@login');
```

Pagina que da o erro:

```
@extends('principal')

@section('conteudo')

<h1>Novo produto</h1>

@if($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    </div>
@endif

<form action="/produtos/adiciona/" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nome</label>
        <input class="form-control" value="{{ old('nome')}}" type="text" name="nome">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Valor</label>
        <input class="form-control" value="{{ old('valor')}}" type="number" name="valor">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Quantidade em estoque</label>
        <input class="form-control" value="{{ old('quantidade')}}" type="number" name="quantidade">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Tamanho</label>
        <input class="form-control" value="{{ old('tamanho')}}" type="text" name="tamanho">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Categoria</label>
        <select class="form-control" type="text" name="categoria_id">
            @foreach($categorias as $c)
                <option value="{{$c->id}}">{{$c->nome}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Descricao</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" value="{{ old('descricao')}}" name="descricao"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
</form>
@stop
```

Quando estava na minha maquina estava rodando tranquilamente, no meu pc roda php 7.1.1 e no servidor roda 7.0

[image: PS da mensagem de erro]

Comment: Você registrou uma rota para `/adiciona`, mas no formulário você o envia para `/produtos/adiciona/`. É isso mesmo? O prefixo do grupo aparece na rota da página `/adiciona`? Se não, você tem que mudar no formulário e remover `/produtos` de `action`.

Comment: coloquei em um grupo para ficar mais fácil de entendimento ai todos que estão no grupo começam de /produtos, logo no fim fica /produtos/adiciona

Comment: tem um erro de digitação: `route::GET('/','ProdutoController@lista');` não seria `Route::GET('/','ProdutoController@lista');` ?

Comment: nao, pois a rota de que ta dando problema é Route::POST('/adiciona', 'ProdutoController@adiciona');